# What is the best way to drag a transformer by dragging from empty areas in Konvajs?

Tags: konvajs, konva, konvajs-reactjs

I'm currently following [this guide](https://konvajs.org/docs/select_and_transform/Basic_demo.html) to select shapes in the stage and put them inside a Transformer.
If possible, I'd like to drag an entire Transformer with all of its content without touching any of the shapes inside.

For example, I have two lines that are far from each other. Both of them are nodes inside a Transformer and can be dragged as long as I click one of those 2 lines. However, if I tried to drag from any of the empty area inside the Transformer nothing would happen (or the transformer would reset, depending on the code).

I'm thinking of adding a transparent Rect (this Rect will always have the same size as the Transformer) to the Transformer and then add any other shape that I want inside the Transformer. Since both the Rect and the Transformer have the same size, I could easily drag the entire Transformer from any "empty area" where my other shapes are not located.

I'm not sure if this is the correct/efficient way to do it. How should I tackle this issue to obtain the best outcome?

Comment: I agree that there seems to be no 'draggable' option for the transformer. It is described in the docs as a 'special kind of group'. I assume that a group is a list of shapes that are, well, grouped for various operations which includes dragging. But it seems sensible that whilst the shapes are in a collection the space between them is not part of that grouping. So what you see when you drag one shape in a group is all shapes in the group being offset individually by the same amount.Your suggestion of adding a temporary transparent rect for dragging the transformer seems sensible - go for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an experimental property `shouldOverdrawWholeArea` for `Konva.Transformer`. It is not in the docs yet.

If you set it to `true` the whole transformer area will be available for drag.

But if you have a transformer on top of other shapes, then shapes will be not listening for regular events (such as `click`, `touchstart` etc). Because the transformer rectangle will overdraw hit area of attached shapes. Even will start working as soon, as you remove such a transformer from them.

```js
const stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: window.innerWidth - 20,
  height: window.innerHeight - 20
});

const layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

const shape1 = new Konva.Circle({
  x: 70,
  y: 70,
  radius: 50,
  fill: 'green'
});
layer.add(shape1);

const shape2 = shape1.clone({
   x: 190,
   y: 90
})
layer.add(shape2);

const tr = new Konva.Transformer({
  nodes: [shape1, shape2],
  shouldOverdrawWholeArea: true
});

layer.add(tr);

layer.draw();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@7.0.3/konva.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Dude, your comment saved my life! Thanks a million 

Comment: @lavrton Is there any way to listen to events of some shapes? i.e by changing Z-index or any other method. if so, can u please guide me.