# KonvaJS, Possible to have a draggable group of images?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, canvas, konvajs, konvajs-reactjs

I'm using [react-konva](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-konva) and I need to be able to drag multiple images at once (not using mutliselect). It appears that Konva handles this by using Groups or Containers.

I looked at the TypeScript files and:

```
export declare class Group extends Container<Group | Shape> {
    _validateAdd(child: Node): void;
}
```

```
export interface ContainerConfig extends NodeConfig {
    clearBeforeDraw?: boolean;
    clipFunc?: (ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) => void;
    clipX?: number;
    clipY?: number;
    clipWidth?: number;
    clipHeight?: number;
}
export declare abstract class Container<ChildType extends Node> extends Node<ContainerConfig> {
```

```
export declare class Image extends Shape<ImageConfig> {
```

It would seem the `Image` is an instance of `Shape` and should therefore be placeable in a `Group`, but I just can't get it to work.

I tried doing:

```
<Group height={<SOME NUMBER>} width={<SOME NUMBER>} draggable>
   {obj.map((obj2: any, idx: number) => {
      return (
        <Image
          X={<SOME NUMBER>}
          Y={<SOME NUMBER>}
          key={idx}
          scale={<SOME NUMBER>}
          image=<SOME IMAGE CONFIG>}
          draggable
        />
      )
   })}
</Group>
```

I tried looking for example by the vanilla API, but couldn't find any. It shows that `Group` should be able to contain `Shape` [api](https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Group.html)

> Group constructor. Groups are used to contain shapes or other groups.

I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions on leveraging provided Konva code to accomplish creating a draggable group of images or perhaps an alternative approach I'm not considering.

Comment: Adding the images to a group and dragging the group works in plain JS - see https://konvajs.org/docs/drag_and_drop/Drag_a_Group.html. You could also associate the images in your own collection and move them sympathetically with the one that is dragged.  Also you might want to consider using a transformer with the rotate and sizing nodes switched off. In which case this question might be of use....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62947885/what-is-the-best-way-to-drag-a-transformer-by-dragging-from-empty-areas-in-konva.   Sorry not a react pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt looks fine to me. In `Konva` a layer may have groups and shapes inside. Any group may have other groups or shapes inside. The image is just a shape.

There is a working demo for you:

```js
const URLImage = ({ url, ...rest }) => {
  const [image] = useImage(url);
  return <Image image={image} {...rest} />;
};

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const images = [
      "https://konvajs.org/assets/lion.png",
      "https://konvajs.org/assets/yoda.jpg"
    ];
    return (
      <Stage width={window.innerWidth} height={window.innerHeight}>
        <Layer>
          <Group draggable>
            {images.map((url, i) => (
              <URLImage url={url} x={i * 120} key={i} />
            ))}
          </Group>
        </Layer>
      </Stage>
    );
  }
}
```

DEMO: https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-bohr-vlcsw?file=/src/index.js

Comment: thank you this helped, the issue was that both group and image were draggable, and therefore I think image drag event overwrote group drag event. Any suggestions on how to tackle that one?

Comment: What kind of drag do you expect with such a configuration? Konva start drag from most down node available for drag.